# Encoding image using Imagemagick using CloudFront Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, imagemagick

Trying to encode an image using a cloudfront URL.  Am able to do it with ffmpeg, but not having luck with ImageMagick when I run a command like:

```
convert "myactualcloudfrontsignedurl" -resize 200x200 /home/filename.jpg
```

When I run it I get these errors:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-88997pPOU-wM5ReVq' @ error/svg.c/ReadSVGImage/3007.

convert: no images defined `/home/filename.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/325
```

I tried to url encode the cloudfront url, but then the url is too long.

After updating the ImageMagick permissions to allow reading of https files, I was able to get a regular image encoded using this command with single quotes:

```
convert 'https://example.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?cat=1' -resize 300x200 cat.jpg
```

However, when I used single quotes with my cloudfront command, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure that you can pass a URL to ImageMagick? I couldn't see any such example in the [convert documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Does it work if you just use a normal URL to an image on the internet?

Comment: Yeah I was able to get it to work for a regular URL.  Updating question.

Comment: does ImageMagick look at content-type from response?